# Await returns pending promises in Typescript

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await, request-promise

I'm a .Net developer new to the javascript/node world and having some trouble making a request to get the HTML from a webpage using request-promise. I've tried variations of the below code.

```
import cheerio = require('cheerio');
import request = require('request-promise');

export class Address {
    public html;
    public $: CheerioStatic;

    constructor() {
         this.html = this.makeRequest();
    }

    private async makeRequest() {
        const options = {
            uri: 'https://www.google.com/',
            transform(body) {
                return cheerio.load(body);
            }
        };
        return await request(options);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I set the this.html variable by calling the this.makeRequest() method I get `Promise { pending }` returned. I'm not sure why this is. From what I've been researching doesn't the await, wait for the promise to be resolved? I've tried it with the `.then` syntax as well, but I get an even stranger result: 
`Promise {_bitField: 0, _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined, _rejectionHandler0: undefined, _promise0: undefined, _receiver0: undefined, …}`. The version of makeRequest() that returns that weird promise is below.

```
private makeRequest() {
    const options = {
        uri: 'https://www.google.com/',
        transform(body) {
            return cheerio.load(body);
        }
    };
    return request(options)
        .then(function($: CheerioStatic) {
            return $;
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            //
        });
}
```

I would like to stick with the async/await syntax, but any help in explaining why my code isn't working and what I could do to fix it would be appreciated!

### Update

Per @basarat suggestion, I made another async method using the await keyword to set the property. My code is below. I also tried with and without the async/await keywords in the getRequest method. Either way, my property is now returned as `undefined`. Not sure if this is a step in the right direction or not.

```
import cheerio = require('cheerio');
import request = require('request-promise');

export class Address {
    public html;
    public $: CheerioStatic;

    constructor() {
        this.getHtml();

        // this.parseHtml();
    }

    private async makeRequest() {
        const options = {
            uri: 'https://www.google.com/',
            transform(body) {
                return cheerio.load(body);
            }
        };
        return await request(options);
    }

    private async getHtml() {
        this.html = await this.makeRequest();
    }
}
```

### Update 2

So, not knowing what to do, I decided to try out the promises route again, with the request module instead of request-promise. In my `makeRequest()` function I'm returning a new promise that wraps my request and then calling `.then()` on it in the `getHtml()` method. Another thing to note is that I'm testing this code via mocha unit tests. Not sure if that has anything to do with it. I've tried making the test async and using await in there as well, but no cigar. Below are my class and test.

```
import request = require('request');

export class Address {
    public html;

    constructor() {
        this.html = this.getHtml();
    }

    public getHtml() {
        this.makeRequest().then((body) => {
            console.log(body);
            return body;
        });
    }

    private makeRequest() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            request('https://www.google.com/', function(error, response, body) {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                }
                resolve(body);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

One last observation. I put in the `console.log(body);` within the getHtml() method to see if it was being called. When I run the unit test and put a breakpoint anywhere in the test, that is never called even though I had created an instance of my class. However, when I continue the execution and finish the test it prints off all of the HTML! So to me, the most recent code seems mostly fine, but maybe there is some sort of timing issue going on. Since the HTML still prints out, the call is at least being made, but it isn't making it to my property. Below is the test I'm executing.

```
describe('Address', () => {
    // const address = new Address();
    it('is not empty', () => {
        const address = new Address();
        const ad = address.html;
        // console.log(ad);
    });
});
```

Also, in the test I have tried making the `it` statement async and adding `await` to the address.html (also have tried awaiting the instantiation), and again no cigar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found a solution! I essentially made an async function that calls the request method and then had to make an async test that awaits my async method call. To summarize, it seems I have to make a method to instantiate everything and cannot do so in the constructor. If someone can shed some light on to why this is, that would be awesome as it seems really counter-intuitive to me. I mean, is that not what a constructor is for? Maybe, I'll post another question about that if I cannot find it anywhere. Anyway, my code is below.

```
import request = require('request');

export class Address {
    public html;

    constructor() {
        //
    }

    public async getHtml() {
        return await this.makeRequest()
            .then((body) => {
                this.html = body;
            });
    }

    public makeRequest() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            request('https://fakena.me/random-real-address/', function(error, response, body) {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                }
                resolve(body);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

And here is my test method.

```
describe('Address', () => {
    // const address = new Address();
    it('is not empty', async () => {
        const address = new Address();
        await address.getHtml();
        console.log(address.html);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> when I set the this.html variable by calling the this.makeRequest() method I get Promise { pending } returned. I'm not sure why this is.

Because `async` functions return a promise.

## Fix

Move call async functions from other async functions (not a constructor) and use await.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. After doing as you suggested, I now get `undefined` returned. I updated my question with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what your class is trying to model. A couple of remarks
 though.
 If your class is modeling some kind of value and trying to hide how this
 value obtained/created inside its private functions it should make its
 consumers aware that it is an "Async" value.
 What this means is although your program compiles because the `this.html` is
 assigned inside an async function, it is actually unavailable before a
 certain event (the resolution of the request in this example). The consumer,
 from the type perspective has no way to know this.

A solution would be to simply assign a promise to `this.html` like

```
class Adress {
  html: Promise<theRealTypeOfHtml>
  ...
  constructor () {
      this.getHtml();
  }
  // no more async
  private getHtml () {
    this.html = this.makeRequest()
  }
}
```

Using this any consumer is now aware that by creating an instance of this
 class it is returned an object which has an `html` field containing a promise
 resolving to whatever you want html to be.
 Practically this means that any consumer of this class will be strongly
 encouraged to use it in an `async` context:

```
async function main () {
  const anAdress = new Adress();
  const html = await anAdress.html;
}
```

In conclusion you just lifted the async context at the consumer level instead
of the producer level.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to make a request for the HTML of a website (not google). I will then parse out my HTML to get an address using Cheerio. I left out some of the properties in order to simplify my code. I supposed changing my class name might have been helpful. The user won't ultimately have access to the this.html property, but for now, I'm just trying to get my code to work before I worry too much about that. I have this exact situation working in C#, so I know it's possible. Using your suggestions, though, hasn't changed my outcome. I'm still getting an `undefined` returned.

Comment: I edited with the correct constructor, no more assignment in it, the assignment to `this.html` is done in `getHtml` with the promise request as  the value.